# Flutter app restarts every time while capturing image from camera on Android devices

Tags: flutter

Flutter app restarts every time while capturing image from camera. We have used image picker plugin for this. version : ^0.6.7+12.

This has been observed mostly in 2GB RAM devices. Please help with this issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may happen due to low memory.

Handling MainActivity destruction on Android
Android system -- although very rarely -- sometimes kills the MainActivity after the image_picker finishes. When this happens, we lost the data selected from the image_picker. You can use retrieveLostData to retrieve the lost data in this situation. For example:

```html
Future<void> retrieveLostData() async {
  final LostData response =
      await picker.getLostData();
  if (response.isEmpty) {
    return;
  }
  if (response.file != null) {
    setState(() {
      if (response.type == RetrieveType.video) {
        _handleVideo(response.file);
      } else {
        _handleImage(response.file);
      }
    });
  } else {
    _handleError(response.exception);
  }
}
```

[MainActivity destruction on Android](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#handling-mainactivity-destruction-on-android)